# Render view past overscan from service

Tags: android, service, navigationbar

I'm creating an app provides a custom navigation bar for rooted Android devices. At this point, I've figured out how to create a navigation bar-like overlay, display it over other apps, hide the default navigation bar system-wide, and add overscan space for the navigation bar to fit in (to prevent it from covering other apps). Now, the only task remaining is to cram the custom navigation into the overscan space:

[image]

Digging through the Android source code, I've discovered that the Android framework provides a window flag as well as a few Themes that allow you to extend an *activity* into overscan space. What I still don't understand is why I can't use the window flag in my *service* to allow it to render my inflated view in the overscan space

**What I've tried:** 
1. Adding the `LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_OVERSCAN` flag to my `WindowManager.LayoutParams` when building the parameters for my overlay.
2. Setting the `fitsSystemWindows` attribute to `false` on the root element in my XML layout that I'm inflating as the overlay 
3. Using negative margins on the layout to pull it below the overscan baseline

If accomplishing this in a service isn't possible, is there any other way to create this 'always-on-top' effect differently so that I at least have a window object to work with?

**NOTE**: Using the holo overscan theme in an activity works exactly as expected. It just doesn't work to use the flag in a service.